# google.maps.Geocoder() incorrectly detect an address

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

There is an address that I want to find on the map **вул Південна 10 місто Одеса**

Looking:

```
...

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=..."></script>

...

function addMarkerByAddress(id, Adres){
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': Adres}, 
        function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
                var marker = addMarker({
                    id: id,
                    position: latlng
                });
            }
        });
}
```

As a result, the marker will appear at: **вул Південна *дорога* 10 місто Одеса**

If you go to maps.google.com and interactively enter there **вул Південна 10 місто Одеса**, Google will detect it correctly.

Is it possible to do something to know if address was defined correctly with google.maps.Geocoder() ?

Comment: The Google Maps API Geocoding Service is not an address validator, it returns the best match and includes information in the response about the quality of the result.

Comment: It looks like in this particular case Geocoding API cannot distinguish between вулиця (street) and дорога (road). I can see that rooftop address 'Південна вулиця, 10' exists with place ID ChIJuzUKXI0xxkARfrqbHGi2d1w, but Geocoding prefer '
Південна дорога, 10' with place ID ChIJfznMCcs6xkARgIFwDavzE4E. Can you use place autocomplete element to solve this situation? Take a look at the Geocoding [best practices](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices).